# ifelse makes factor 'forget' its levels order

Tags: r, factors

I have a data frame with two factors, like this one:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = factor(rep(letters[1:3], 2)),
  y = factor(rep(c('z','x','y'), each=2), c('z','x','y'))
)

 data
  x y
1 a z
2 b z
3 c x
4 a x
5 b y
6 c y
```

I want to turn all the `y`s for which `x` is `a` into `NA`s. So I try:

```
factor(ifelse(data$x=='a', NA, as.character(data$y)))
<NA> z    x    <NA> y    y   
Levels: x y z
```

to get different levels order than in original data, which was:

```
data$y
z z x x y y
Levels: z x y
```

Can you suggest any way to keep original ordering, other than brute force like this:

```
factor(ifelse(data$x=='a', NA, as.character(data$y)), c('z','x','y'))
<NA> z    x    <NA> y    y   
Levels: z x y
```

Comment: `data[data$x == "a", "y"] <- NA` (Personally, I almost never use `ifelse` in my code.)

Comment: Thank you! Why not turning this to an answer?

Comment: It's too trivial.

Comment: useful + short > trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method looks well. If you don't want to set new levels manually, you can take levels of `data$y` as reference.

```
factor(ifelse(data$x == 'a', NA, as.character(data$y)), levels(data$y))

# [1] <NA> z    x    <NA> y    y   
# Levels: z x y
```

You can also use `replace()`, which doesn't reset levels.

```
replace(data$y, data$x == 'a', NA)

# [1] <NA> z    x    <NA> y    y   
# Levels: z x y
```

Comment: I like `replace` solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `[]` to preserve the factor attributes:

```
data$y[] <- ifelse(data$x=='a', NA, as.character(data$y)) 
str(data$y)
# Factor w/ 3 levels "z","x","y": NA 1 2 NA 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Roland's comment, which is excellent solution, I came with `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data %>% 
  mutate(y = y %>% inset(x=='a', value=NA)) %>% 
  pull(y)

<NA> z    x    <NA> y    y   
Levels: z x y
```

Maybe it would be useful for someone :)

Another option, thanks to Darren Tsai:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(y = y %>% replace(x=='a', NA)) %>% 
  pull(y)

<NA> z    x    <NA> y    y   
Levels: z x y
```